# Component uses a device - failed to allocateCapacity

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using Redhawk 1.9. I have create a dummy device that is used by a dummy component. I have a dummy node containing the dummy device. A dummy waveform which has the dummy component. I am having two problems:

- In the Device Manager Console (launch in IDE from TARGET SDR) I get the warning message that indicates the Device is unable to connect to IDM channel. I checked to make sure the Naming and Event service was still up. I am uncertain to track down this problem. I launch the Device Manager with a logging at trace level, but I didn't see anything to help me.

INFO:DeviceManager - Starting Device Manager with /nodes/DummyNode/DeviceManager.dcd.xml
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Connecting to Domain Manager REDHAWK_DEV/REDHAWK_DEV
INFO:DeviceManager - Starting ORB!
WARN:Device_impl - Unable to connect to IDM channel
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device DummyDevice_1 on Device Manager DummyNode
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Initializing device DummyDevice_1 on Device Manager DummyNode
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device DummyDevice_1 on Domain Manager

- When I launch the Dummy Waveform from the IDE, I get an invalidCapacity error message. The dummy component uses the dummy device. It looks for the property device_kind = dummy_device_kind. I overrode the allocateCapacity method in the DummyDevice to return true. I check out the dummyDevice in the python command line and the allocateCapacity return true.

Error Message:

```
NFO:DomainManager_impl - Installing application /waveforms/DummyWaveform/DummyWaveform.sad.xml
DEBUG:ComponentInfo - Loading component properties from /components/DummyComponent/DummyComponent.prf.xml
DEBUG:ComponentInfo - Parsing component properties
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - UsesDevice Impl Vec of length 1
DEBUG:ComponentImplementationInfo - Attempting to match allocation properties
DEBUG:ComponentImplementationInfo - Trying to match for property id DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d
DEBUG:ComponentImplementationInfo -  It's a matching prop
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - Trying to find the device
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - Device Allocation Failed.. need to clean up
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - --FAILED-- Allocation of component's implementation cpp of DummyComponent_1. Undoing allocate devices
ERROR:ApplicationFactory_impl - The following CORBA exception occurred: InvalidCapacity while creating the application
INFO:DomainManager_impl - Uninstalling application DCE:8d0a6e63-24f6-4766-9a3f-7db7fd516078
```

Comment: The allocation error failed because I didn't have the following allocation properties defined: processor_name, os_name, and os_version. When a component is created by the IDE, the default is for these properties to be required. I was able to figure this out by using trace level of debugging.

Comment: I am still working on why my device is not able to connect to IDM Channel.

Comment: The allocation problems are taken care by including GPP in the node. See the answer to the following question: "Component unable to allocate device that is not Executable Device" 12/9/2012

Comment: The IDM Channel problem was answer in a later question: "Unable to connect to IDM_Channel" - 12/2/2013

Answer (score 0):

As far as your event channel problem, double-check your domain manager's startup messages. For example, when I start the domain manager without omniEvents running, I see:

```
$ nodeBooter -D
INFO:DomainManager - Starting Domain Manager
WARN:EventChannelSupport - Event channel REDHAWK_DEV.ODM_Channel not created
WARN:EventChannelSupport - Event channel REDHAWK_DEV.IDM_Channel not created
INFO:DomainManager - Starting ORB!
```

If omniEvents appears started, but the domain still seems to have problems creating the event channels, you might try resetting omniEvents. See [Appendix H, Section 6](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap8.html#x34-439000H.6) of the documentation.

If you don't see warning messages from your domain manager, then I would use nameclt to verify that the event channels are showing up in your domain, for example:

```
$ nameclt list REDHAWK_DEV
ODM_Channel
IDM_Channel
REDHAWK_DEV
```

You can also use eventviewer to help debug/view events. Depending on whether the event channel is registered or not, you'd see either:

```
$ eventviewer REDHAWK_DEV IDM_Channel
Receiving events. Press 'enter' key to exit
```

if things are working, or if not:

```
$ eventviewer REDHAWK_DEV IDM_Channel
No such channel exists
```

Comment: The event channel, IDM_Channel, appears to be working fine. I notice that I didn't get this message with GPP device when I put it into my dummy node. So I tried creating from the IDE a default device (default settings on everything) with a C++ and Python implementation. When putting them into a node create by the IDE (all default settings) the C++ version had this warning, while the python version did not.

Comment: I put the USRP device into the dummy node and I got the same warning message for that device.

Comment: INFO:DeviceManager - Starting Device Manager with /nodes/DummyNode/DeviceManager.dcd.xml
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Connecting to Domain Manager REDHAWK_DEV/REDHAWK_DEV
INFO:DeviceManager - Starting ORB!
linux; GNU C++ version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3); Boost_104100; UHD_003.005.004-143-gde4ce9ea

WARN:Device_impl - Unable to connect to IDM channel
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device USRP_UHD_1 on Device Manager DummyNode
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Initializing device USRP_UHD_1 on Device Manager DummyNode